# How do I get XFCE to show the Desktop directory on the desktop instead of the home directory?

Tags: xubuntu, 13.10, xfce

I just installed Xubuntu 13.10. I replaced the Desktop directory with a symlink to a directory on another partition (I've been doing this for a while). It worked fine at first, but then I did something that broke the mounting of the partition that Desktop is on. After that, the desktop was showing the contents of the home directory. I fixed the mounting issue and rebooted. I can verify that the target of the Desktop link is properly mounted and there, but the desktop still shows the contents of the home directory. How do I change it back?

(Found [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1706643), but it appears to be Gnome-specific.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found it... it's in the file `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`. Change the line

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/"
```

to

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
```

Did a full reboot (relog might have sufficed) and my desktop is back. I also had to change a few more lines in that file, as I had similarly linked a couple of the other "special" directories.

Comment: Logging out the user and logging back in is sufficient.  There is no need for a full reboot.

Comment: The desktop is powered by a running instance of `xfdesktop`.  If it is killed it will automatically restart and re-read your new settings.  After making the changes, you can issue the command `killall xfdesktop` to get them to take effect.